# Distributional derivative of a function

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Let us consider the function $f(x)=e^{-|x-a|}\chi_{\{x\leq a\}}$. I want to compute the distributional derivative. Let us consider a test function $\phi\in\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. Now
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\phi'(x)\ dx
&=\int_{-\infty}^ae^{-|x-a|}\phi'(x)\ dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^ae^{x-a}\phi'(x)\ dx\\
&=\left[e^{x-a}\phi(x)\right]_{-\infty}^a-\int_{-\infty}^ae^{x-a}\phi(x)\ dx\\
&=\phi(a)-\int_{-\infty}^ae^{x-a}\phi(x)\ dx\\
&=-\left(\int_{-\infty}^ae^{x-a}\phi(x)\ dx-\phi(a)\right)\\
&=-\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(e^{-|x-a|}\chi_{\{x\leq a\}}-\delta(x-a)\phi(x)\ dx\right).
\end{align*}Hence distributional derivative $$f'(x)=e^{x-a}-\delta(x-a).$$Is that logical or correct?

Answer (score 0):

Foreword: I use " ' " as the distributional derivative.

Also $e^{-|x-a|}\chi_{x\leq a} = e^{x-a}\chi_{x\leq a}$

Consider this, shortly:

$$\left(e^{-|x-a|}\chi_{x\leq a}\right)' = e^{x-a}\chi_{x\leq a} + e^{x-a}\delta(x-a) = e^{x-a}\chi_{x\leq a} - \delta(x-a) $$

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC, aha... but/and I wonder whether that might be a typo...

Comment: Yes there was typo. But why in my calculation minus sign coming before dirac delta. Any wrong?

Comment: No, this is the above computation that is wrong, the derivative of $\chi_{x\leq a}$ is $-\delta(x-a)$ (the function is decreasing). Your computation @Jacobi is correct.